# Android Graphics Effects

Tags: android, graphics, effects, andengine

I'm developing a new game using AndEngine Game Framework
I wanted to know what is the best way to make graphics animation effects?
for example, a Sprite fading etc..

thanks a lot
David

Answer (score 0):

Take look at the AndEngineExamples project on Github
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples